How do I install ALL optional dependencies?
I am specifically looking at WINE, but general advice on how to do this would also be welcome.
I am used to ARCH where you have convenient options to install all optional dependencies for an app.
Is there a way to do this for UBUNTU?  Perhaps a package manager for Ubuntu with such an option, or a terminal command?

A simple apt command will install all required dependencies; only the dpkg command requires they be pre-installed OR installed in the same command.  The package tools do requires your sources have requirements available.

On Ubuntu there isn't a way to do this...But you can "workaround" the issue partially. For example, for Wine, you can install all dependencies with:
sudo apt install wine wine-recommends

This will install the necessary dependencies, but it is possible that some "non-essential" packages will be left out, and you may need to install them manually.

When I use the command I get the error message:  E: Unable to locate package wine-recommends

Dependencies are never optional. Suggested packages are, and you can use apt-get --install-suggests install wine to install them.

When I use the command I get the error message:  E: Invalid operation wine

Thanks @VincentWood :~)
